# How to make SVG “fill” act in a similar way to CSS “background-position:right top”

Tags: css, svg

I have the following SVG image:

```html
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" viewBox="0 0 66.667 108">
    <pattern id="i" width="100%" height="100%">
    <image xlink:href="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/3/38/Bangalore_Panorama_edit1.jpg" width="45" height="49" preserveAspectRatio="xMinYMin slice"/>
    </pattern>
    <rect x="21.667" y="0" width="45" height="49" fill="url(#i)"/>
    </svg>
```

I need the rectangle to fill with an image equivalent to the following CSS syntax:

```
background-size:cover;
background-image:url("image.jpg");
background-repeat:no-repeat;
background-position:right top;
```

[Thanks to this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23227195/how-to-make-svg-fill-act-in-a-similar-way-to-css-background-size-cover), I got them all except background-position:right top. Is this possible in an SVG image? If so, how can I achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

To mimic the behavior, so that the top right corner of the picture is located at the top right corner of the `rect`, you just need to change the `preserveAspectRatio="xMinYMin slice"` of the `image` to `preserveAspectRatio="xMaxYMin slice"`:

```html
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" viewBox="0 0 66.667 108">
    <pattern id="i" width="100%" height="100%">
    <image xlink:href="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/3/38/Bangalore_Panorama_edit1.jpg" width="45" height="49" preserveAspectRatio="xMaxYMin slice"/>
    </pattern>
    <rect x="21.667" y="0" width="45" height="49" fill="url(#i)"/>
    </svg>
```